# Is mandatory to refer foreign key even it has only one parent?

Tags: python, django

lets assume that there is an institution and this institution has many announcement so I intend to store these announcements in a table.

Here is how it looks,

```
class institution:
  - name
  - address,
  - .....etc

class announcements:
  - owner = models.ForeignKey(Institution, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  - messages,
  - ...etc
```

From this, there wont be any new Institution, so do i really need to add FK in announcements table ?or can i simply create a table without FK as i can directly call the announcements without need to FK

Comment: as  i undestand   one   institution   can have one  or many announcements   so to display that kind of relationship  in database level youn need  a foreign key  of institution in the announcments  table   for better explanation you can check the docs  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: the foreign key  is the connection between the two tables  if you remove the foreign key there is no other column to show that table connection. You could have one table but then you will have duplicate data. read this article  https://www.educative.io/blog/what-is-foreign-key-database

Comment: Ya understood, why should i need a connection ! I can directly call the announcement class and add data to it right ?

Comment: You can add  an announcement for a specific institution

Comment: Ya, but there is non more institution, its default institution there wont be any addition

Comment: You design your models based on you projects requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you absolutely can - your design is that you have one institution and so all announcements will relate to that institution and there is no doubt about that. However, this means that you cannot in future add announcements for another institution if the purpose of your application were to change without having to change your model to include said FK relation. This isn't really a big deal but you would have to change not only your models but also your views to connect the two.